# How I can get the ID of an embed | Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I created an embed and want to get the ID in the same function:

```
embedVar = discord.Embed(title="TEXT", description="TEXT", color=0x00ff00)
embedVar.add_field(name="TEXT", inline=False)
embedVar.set_footer(text="TEXT")

await channel.send(embed=embedVar)

get ID of embedVar
```

Now I want to get the ID of the embed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get it by doing this:

```py
message = await channel.send(embed = embedVar)
id = message.id
```